# Разобрать простой JSON ответ на jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsonp

php

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 1000');
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');

echo 'online({"usr":"Admin","prj":"текст"}, {"usr":"Admin2","prj":"текст2"})';
```

Его нужно распарсить и вставить, как мне кажется циклом в `div`. Должно быть в итоге.

```
<font title="текст">Admin</font>, <font title="текст2">Admin2</font>
```

Что смог сделал - код представляю вам ниже. Цикл не возвращает ничего

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'online.php',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    jsonpCallback: 'online',
    crossDomain: true,
    type: 'GET',
    data: { 'online': 'show' },
    cache: false,
    success: function(data){    
        i = 0;
        while ( i < data.length ){
            alert(data[i].usr);
            i++;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: i = 0;
    while ( i < data.length )
    {
 alert(data[i].User);
 i++;
    } тоже не работает

Comment: console.log(data) дает вам строку или массив? Насколько я понимаю, в вашем примере невалидный JSON или вы не весь его нам показываете

Comment: @tutankhamun подредактировал вопрос. всё правильно, но не работает. console.log(data) внутри цикла ничего не даёт, а не внутри даёт строку

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пофантазирую.

1. Если вы получаете ответ от стороннего скрипта, то в том виде, который вы указали он неправильный. Но если вы не можете на это повлиять, придется принудительно парсить

   var obj = jQuery.parseJSON('[' + data + ']');
2. Если скрипт ваш, то тогда нужно добиться выдачи валидного JSON объекта (или массива) со стороны сервера

**Добавлено** После редактирования вопроса стало понятнее. У вас неправильно обрабатывается JSONP ответ. Ответ будет загружен в виде скрипта и будет вызвана функция `online` с двумя параметрами. И объявлять `success` не имеет смысла. Еще, если вы хотите в цикле перебирать объекты, сделайте так, чтобы в функцию передавался массив

```
echo 'online([{"usr":"Admin","prj":"текст"}, {"usr":"Admin2","prj":"текст2"}])';
```

На стороне браузера должна быть функция типа:

```
function online(users) {
    for (var ix = 0, len = users.length; ix < len; ix += 1) {
        // делаем что-то с users[ix]
    }
}
```

Comment: посмотрите, отредактировал, теперь валидный ответ

Comment: как исправить ?

Comment: спасибо, работает

Answer (score -1):

Попробуй так:

```
success: function(data) {
   var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
   ...
}
```

Comment: и как сие чудо использовать?

Comment: console.log(obj) даёт null

Comment: var json = '{"User":"Тут текст 1", "User 2":"Тут текст 2"}';
function ded(data){
    var objc = jQuery.parseJSON(data);

   for (var i in objc) {
       $('#online').append('<p>'+ i +' => ' + objc[i] + '</p>');
   }
}